# WPBakery Page builder showing code in UI page in theme

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

In blog theme There are two pages
1) All Post in one page
2) Detail post page

To build page we are using wpbakery 
When we see the page type 1(All post in one page) some of page bakery's back end code is showing where as It should be design.

Where as page 2(detail post) is working fine.

Here is Image for Blog list page.
[image: blog page with wpbakery not working]

Image for Page 2 Blog detail.
[image: Detail page with wpbakery working fine]

Is the issue of theme or wpBakery page builder plugin?

Comment: Did you made the template yourself?

Comment: No we have purchased theme

Comment: Can you check the template outputting the content? It's either that the content is not outputted correctly to execute shortcode, or that the builder save the generated shortcode in text mode instead of visual mode.

Comment: while edit the page it showing correctly in visual mode

Comment: And for the template outputting other codes are working if I see for other post it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created ticket with WPBakery Page builder, Moved all code to another server and updated again with fresh WPBakery plugin download.

Now it is working fine. Just update the php version and it's working fine.